# HTML local storage multiple keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Wanting to be able to have multiple people take a survey then refresh etc. Anyway to store multiple keys to local storage without overwriting the previous? Group by a userID or sorts?

```
$('form').submit(function() {
     $('input, select, textarea').each(function() {
       var value = $(this).val(),
           name = $(this).attr('name');
       localStorage[name] = value;

     console.log('stored key: '+name+' stored value: '+value);
});   
});
```

project in whole: http://jsfiddle.net/PVGUq/

Comment: If depends on the numbers and size of your values. A simple solution would be to store (as JSON) an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store JSON instead of plain text. For the maximum storage size see [What is the max size of localStorage values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values)

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

localStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(items));

items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myKey'));

items.length; //4
```